# Bluemix Mobile Analytics: Can't see logging data sent from my app

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud, analytics, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to use the Bluemix Mobile Analytics platform. I am not having any issues setting up my Android and Swift SDKs to send logs. However, the Mobile Analytics dashboard does not seem to be that intuitive.

I am seeing my logging requests come in to the dashboard. However, I want to be able to see the logging information that is coming from the mobile apps.

How do I view the logging data that is being sent into the analytics dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the logging information in the Mobile Dashboard by clicking the **Troubleshooting** tab and clicking **Search**:

**Log Search:**

[image: log search view]

**Expanded log:**

[image: expanded logs]

Comment: Joe, I appreciate you providing to me this step. However, the search bar acts more like a filter than an actual search function. If I initialize a Logger object in Android for example, add text like "load completed", and then push my logs to the server using the Logger.send function, I should be able to see this new entry. In fact, I do receive a success on the callback in the mobile app. However, this value is not seen anywhere in the server. What am I supposed to use to view comments like this? This should be simple but nothing is working. Please advise

Comment: Could you send me your logging statement and logging level? (e.g.
`Logger.setLogLevel(Logger.LEVEL.INFO);)`)

Comment: It can take a little time to store the logs, so sometimes they won't show up immediately.

Comment: Joe, I appreciate you helping out with this. I have since been able to see some logging. I think I had some things screwed up on the client. Thanks again for the help.